# Project Empty - Android

Tags: android

I have been trying to start with a basic app from the tutorial , but when i try to create the second activity . The eclipse doesn't suggest the project name. The dropdown is empty. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Post some screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Restart eclipse and try following --

Just Select your project at left side project list and clean.
Now click on new button from shortcut menu, go to android,then select android activity,then blank activity and other things if you want change then finish.

If it is still not solved, create new project.

Comment: The clean option itself is disabled when i select the project name in the "outline" tab  .  Any chances of me missing a class in the MainActivity.Java file ?

Comment: Then its problem with your ide either you just created some wrong type of project. You need to reinstall ide and create new project and do whatever you want.